# Vba code to open multiple files in separate sheets of the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel, openfiledialog, worksheet

I have a code that allows me to open a file in an excel workbook, however I want to be able to open multiple files within the same workbook named p00001, p00002, p00003 and so on. Does anyone know how I can edit my code to select all the files named this way and open them in separate sheets in the same workbook?

My code is:

```
Sub Open_Workbook()

    Dim my_FileName As Variant

    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename

    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of Files are those?

Comment: You could loop through all the Excel files in a folder and do what you wanted, would that work?

Comment: The files are dat files and yes I would like to be able to loop somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this solution i used the FileDialog for Selecting Multiple Files.
After that, you need to Loop all thoes Files a for Loop.
Inside the For Loop, you have to Open the File and Import the Sheet. In this Example i Imported all the Sheets the Workbook has.
After the Code is done Importing you close the Source Workbook and do the Same for the Rest of the Files.

```
Sub Import Files()
        Dim sheet As Worksheet
        Dim total As Integer
        Dim intChoice As Integer
        Dim strPath As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim wbNew As Workbook
        Dim wbSource As Workbook
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add


        'allow the user to select multiple files
        Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True
        'make the file dialog visible to the user
        intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        'determine what choice the user made
        If intChoice <> 0 Then
            'get the file path selected by the user
            For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems.Count
                strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(i)

                Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

                For Each sheet In wbSource.Worksheets
                    total = wbNew.Worksheets.Count
                    wbSource.Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
                    after:=wbNew.Worksheets(total)
                Next sheet

                wbSource.Close
            Next i
        End If

    End Sub
```

If you want to get all Files From a Directory you can change the ApplicationFile Dialog with a Loop were you Loop the Directory Like This:

```
 directory = "c:\test\"
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
    Do While fileName <> ""
    'Put Code From For Loop here.
    Loop
```